# Ligase Chain Reaction: Determining the annealing temperature for gene synthesis

Tags: protocol, gene-synthesis, lcr

Using the tool [Gene2Oligo](http://berry.engin.umich.edu/gene2oligo/index.html) I have a set of DNA oligonucleotides to synthesize a gene using ligase chain reaction (LCR).  The average melting temperature is 72 degrees Celsius.  I am going to use a the thermostable Taq ligase enzyme for the LCR reaction but I am unsure of the annealing temperature to use.  Should I use the standard recommendation as in PCR of 5 degrees less than the melting temperature or should I use another tool?  Taq ligase has a cutoff in activity at 65C so that is the highest I can use.